# Extjs 4 and Draw2D touch JavaScript GraphLib

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc, draw2d-js

i am trying to build an app with extjs 4 and draw2d touch library. the app has a two column panel. how can i drag a draw2d shape from one column and drop it in the other? Any help plis
thanks[image: workspace]

Comment: Did you read the doc on drag and drop in ExtJs ? Can you share the code you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

draw2d touch use the jquery-ui dragdrop stuff. You must add a css class **"draw2d_droppable"** to your div
to indicate that the node is dragable. You can introspec thte example "buildin_commandstack" from draw2d.

```
   <div id="navigation" class="">
        <div data-shape="draw2d.shape.node.Start"   class="palette_node_element draw2d_droppable">Start</div>
        <div data-shape="draw2d.shape.node.End"     class="palette_node_element draw2d_droppable">End</div>
        <div data-shape="draw2d.shape.node.Between" class="palette_node_element draw2d_droppable">Between</div>
   </div>
```

Regards